# How do i apply Table Header color to Table body using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET MVC pplication. It has functionality to show monthly figures using Table. It is showing according to the Quarter so it is dynamically creating. Each month showing as 
Week -1 Week -2 Week -3 Week -4 like that. this names are showing on the table header section.
For each month background shown as different color I already implemented show these things. Now it is showing Table headers in colors.My Problem is how do i apply this background color to table tds? It should be shown in coloumnwise.I am going to use JQuery.

Eg:
If coloumn header one is red each column td should be background color is same.

Edit : Here is the jsfiddle.net/ucfs8/ 
I tried to insert jsfiddle shown error please go to that link for jsfiddle

Edit Edit: Solution is OKIs there any way to do this using CSS only because JQuery is slow when dril down the application.Actually this is based on Tree Structure. When you click on on Node then it drill down to sub nodes.one node have about 10 sub nodes. then take time to load using JQuery. Thanks.

Comment: you have tried jsfiddle?

Comment: Why jQuery? Why not just CSS?

Comment: you are using grid view?

Comment: @rps No is just Html table written using Razor

Comment: you can add classes to your table rows then... mind sharing the code in your question?

Comment: that fiddle has static client-side code  not the one with the razor code, the headers are dynamically created too? why not while creating the <td>s just add a corresponding class? say <td class='sep'> then you can add a particular color for that class, I am sorry If that's not a possiblity, never used .net mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are generating the table yourself just add a col group to it and style that.

Something like ([jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/validide/6XZc8/)):

```
<colgroup>
        <col style="width: 3%; background-color: whitesmoke" />
        <col style="width: 10%; background-color: whitesmoke" />
        <col style="width: 11%; background-color: whitesmoke" />
        <col style="background-color:#ebcccc" />
        <col style="background-color:#ebcccc" />
        <col style="background-color:#ebcccc" />
        <col style="background-color:#ebcccc" />
        <col style="background-color:#dff0d8" />
        <col style="background-color:#dff0d8" />
        <col style="background-color:#dff0d8" />
        <col style="background-color:#dff0d8" />
        <col style="background-color:#dff0d8" />
        <col style="background-color:#d9edf7" />
        <col style="background-color:#d9edf7" />
        <col style="background-color:#d9edf7" />
        <col style="background-color:#d9edf7" />
        <col style="background-color:#d0e9c6" />
        <col style="background-color:#d0e9c6" />
        <col style="background-color:#d0e9c6" />
        <col style="background-color:#d0e9c6" />
        <col style="background-color:#d0e9c6" />
        <col/>
</colgroup>
```

Ideally you would use some css class :D

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to find wich column interest you it should be easy:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var color = $("table>thead th").css("background-color")
     $("table>tbody td").css("background-color", color)
}
```

You can select each column with the number child selector, something like:

```
for(...length){
   var color = $("table>thead th:nth-child(1)").css("background-color");
   $("table>tbody td:nth-child(1)").css("background-color", color)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check here, UPDATE DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/ucfs8/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var col = $('table tr td');
    $('table tbody tr').each(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color','whitesmoke');
        for (var i = 0; i <= col.length; i++) {
            var color = $('table th').eq(i).css('background-color');
            $(this).find('td').eq(i).css('background-color', color);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can we do this using CSS only?